# Windows Mobile deletes my Contacts when deleting a partnership

Tags: windows-mobile, contacts, activesync

Sometimes when I reinstall my PC get a new Work PC or buy a new home PC ,ActiveSync, now the Device Center asks me to delete an existing partnership to setup a partnership with the new PC, since only two partnerships are allowed.

When I delete that partnership all contacts that originally came from that partnership get deleted too. How can I prevent that from happening. Do I really always have to remember to frequently backup all my contacts in a safe place? How much redundancy is needed. I hat them on one of my PCs and on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into root of your device and make a copy of *.pim file.
Delete partnership and you will notice that there are no contacts any more.
Restore saved *.pim file and your contacts will reappear.

Do notice that sometime you will get "file in use" errors when replacing *.pim file. Just reboot your mobile phone and try again.

If you do not see *.pim file in root of your phone, download some file manager.

Comment: That works. Allthough it is too late for me now. Why (oh why) is this implemented that way? Do you happen to know how I can make my phone and ActivceSync/Device Center FORGET that the contacts once came from a PC and breakup the association?

Comment: Only method of forgetting I know is this one. I am not aware that you could "disconnect" contact from it's source any other way.